# How to convert this "Tue Nov 13 14:35:04 +0000 2012" String format to date in Java?

Tags: java, date

How to convert the date `Tue Nov 13 14:35:04 +0000 2012` String format to date in Java?
I know of `Date.parse(String)` but I don't know which format I should use for the date. Do I have to modify the string so that it can be parsed into date, and if yes then how?

Comment: I think the format is `FULL` [my source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html). any way, what have you tried?

Comment: The JavaDoc for [`Date.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)) suggests using `SimpleDateFormat`, as in the answer below.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
 Date test = sdf.parse("Tue Nov 13 14:35:04 +0000 2012");
 System.out.print(test.toString());
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), with a format string of

```
"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```

You should explicitly use `Locale.US` assuming these will definitely use English month/day names. (You don't want to be trying to parse French names just because the default locale is French, for example.)

Also, don't forget that the `Date` value returned will have no knowledge of the original time zone - it will have the right value for the *instant* represented in the original text, but don't expect the result of calling `toString()` to use the same zone - `Date.toString()` always uses the default time zone.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Your comment would have been considerably more helpful if you'd indicated in what *way* it's incorrect (or just edited the answer).